# How to take only numbers in file by Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command, sh

My problem is to find persons attendance , but he has given his date twice with wrong patterns as **jul22**, **22jul**.  I want to prove that both are same.

The ***attendF***  file data looks like -

```
PersonsName,month
sriram,jul22 
sriram,22jul
```

My idea: first I take the pattern for the months he given in a **attendF** file
 `#grep -i "personName" attendF | cut -t"," -k2,2 > mnthFile`

***mnthFile*** has data like:

```
 jul22
 jul23
 22jul
 jul24
 23 jul
```

I want output to be: 
 jul22
 jul23 
 jul24 
   (or)
 22jul
 23 jul
 jul24
there by I can get his correct attendance.

Comment: what exactly do you want the output to be? Why not type it up like you typed up mnthFile?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem or interview question.   What have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: i am new to shell script and unix commands. i read all man pages of uniq and sort and grep. but i did't find the solution

Comment: We don't need to know what you've read, we need to know what you've tried.

Comment: The question is somewhat wrong since there can be 2 Sriram coming on same date there should be something unique in them atleast roll no or something of that sort which will be in some pattern. The best way to do would be reject such input.

Comment: Your actual question reads like you are looking for `tr -dc '0-9\n' <file`

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to normalise different dates into a single format so you can compare them, the following `normalise` function (along with a small test harness) will do that for you.

It first lower-cases the string then removes all characters that are neither alpha nor numeric.

Then, if it's neither `alpha-number` nor `number-alpha`, it just returns a suitable error value `?`.

However, assuming it *is* of one of those formats, it separates it into day and month then returns it in a consistent format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

normalise() {
        # Lowercase it and remove non-alphanumerics.

        str="$(echo "$1" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sed 's/[^a-z0-9]//g')"

        # Check one of the allowed formats.

        if [[ ! "${str}" =~ ^[0-9]+[a-z]+$ ]] ; then
                if [[ ! "${str}" =~ ^[a-z]+[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
                        echo '?'
                        return
                fi
        fi

        # Extract the day andd month, return normalised value.

        day="$(echo "$str" | sed 's/[a-z]//g')"
        mon="$(echo "$str" | sed 's/[0-9]//g')"
        echo "${day}-${mon}"
}

echo $(normalise "Jul 22")
echo $(normalise "jUl-22")
echo $(normalise "juL22")
echo $(normalise "Jul.22")
echo $(normalise "22 jUl")
echo $(normalise "22-juL")
echo $(normalise "22Jul")
echo $(normalise "22.jUl")
echo $(normalise "22.jUl.1977")
```

The output of that script is:

```
22-jul
22-jul
22-jul
22-jul
22-jul
22-jul
22-jul
22-jul
?
```